How to extracting only the Token from RestAPI response
I have this code that gets the token from RestAPI
// Prepare JSON content
  var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      Console.WriteLine("Token received: " + responseBody);



      return responseBody;
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"Failed to obtain access token (GetAccessToken). Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
      return null;
  }

The return responseBody;
It includes the token but other items as well (token,refresh..). Looks like this:
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNzE5MDI0ODM2LCJleHAiOjE3MTkwMjU0MzYsImlhdCI6MTcxOTAyNDgzNn0.USYqigcN_vGa5tfEaOW0u9RvPpWQIOLdyRb05Fc0RII","refreshToken":""}
I’ve tried
//deserialize token
 var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseBody);
 return outObject.access.token;

but did not work.  Read some post in this forum but the token format was different.
How do I convert that into just the token string before I return it?

Are you connecting to a standards-compliant OAuth2 / OIDC token endpoint - or something more ad-hoc? If it's the former, then you should be using an OAuth2/OIDC+JWT library instead of trying to do things like use JsonConvert on a JWT response (it won't work: you need to segment and decode the JWT into its three componnets (header, payload, signature) and always verify the signature!) before you can use the JSON payload.

Have you tried outObject.token?

Approach 1
Create a model class (TokenResponse) and deserialize the JSON as TokenResponse.
public class TokenResponse
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseBody);
return outObject.Token;


Approach 2
Working with JObject and extract the token field.
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var outJObject = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
return outJObject["token"].ToString();


You can create a generic method for json serialization and deserialization as below
// NOTE HERE: I am using System.Text.Json
using System.Text.Json;

namespace DemoApp.Extensions;

public static class JsonSerializerExtensionMethods
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    };

    public static string ToJson<T>(this T @object, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions = null)
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize(@object, jsonSerializerOptions ?? options);

    public static byte[] ToJsonToUtf8Bytes<T>(this T @object, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions = null)
        => JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(@object, jsonSerializerOptions ?? options);

    // This is the method you need to extract your json data
    public static T? FromJson<T>(this string text, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions = null)
        => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(text, jsonSerializerOptions ?? options);

    public static T? FromJson<T>(this byte[] mByte, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions = null)
        => mByte is null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(mByte, jsonSerializerOptions ?? options);
}

With a class as below.
public class TokenResponse
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

You can now use it to extract your body as below.
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Token received: " + responseBody);

//NOTICE HERE HOW I HAVE USED THE "FromJson"
var tokenResponseResult = responseBody.FromJson<TokenResponse>();
Console.WriteLine("Token token received: " + tokenResponseResult.Token);

Hope it helps.
